# NetLogo: how to find the mean/sum number of turtles per patch?

Tags: netlogo

I want to calculate the mean (or min/max) number of turtles per patch of specific color. I suppose that I have to use something like `show max-one-of patches with [pcolor = red] [count turtles-here]` but if I use it, I get as a result p.ex. patch 0 1. However, I want to know the count of the turtles on this patch, without using `inspect patch 0 1`. When I run `ask patches with [pcolor = red] [sum turtles-here]` I have an error `expected comand`.

Thank you for every suggestion !

```
to setup
  clear-all
  crt 1000 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ] ; randomly distribute turtles
  setup-patches
  show max-one-of patches with [pcolor = red] [count turtles-here] ; show patch with max number of turtles here
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor green]
  ask n-of (count patches / 2) patches [set pcolor red]  ; turn half of patches red
  ; ask patches with [pcolor = red] [sum turtles-here] ; - how to run this?
end

; how to count max number of turtles per red patch?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually trickier than it appears. The `turtles-here` primitive creates the agentset of turtles on the caller's patch and the following code will run through all the red patches, then create a list of the turtle counts. You can see this yourself by putting a print statement in front of it, and you will get a list of numbers.

```
  [count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = red]
```

It is then straightforward to take the mean (or similarly for max or min) of that list.

```
  mean [count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = red]
```